# A bit larger spread between rows of a 2x2 table

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting

The following is my expression:

```
\begin{equation}
\left[
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       $y$ & $a_{bc}$ \\
       \hline
       $a_{ab}^T$ & $y$
  \end{tabular}
\right].
\end{equation}
```

Note that the part a_{ab}^T is very close to the hline. I would like to have a bit larger spacing, such that 'T' from the above example is clearly separated from the hline. I've tried using [pt], but it did not work. I'm using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
```

Comment: See [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are in the math mode anyway, you can use the `array` environment to avoid the `$` pairs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left[
{
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{array}{c|c}
       y & a_{bc} \\
       \hline
       a_{ab}^T & y
  \end{array}
}
\right].
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would also recommend you to look at the [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) package for more goodies regarding the matrix environments.

Comment: One of most useful posts I have seen recently. Thanks a lot for pointing out mathtools package!

Comment: @PredragPunosevac Thank you! But I'm merely harvesting the other great answers.